# ToggleButton change background when pressed (but only once)

Tags: c#, wpf, styles

When a button gets pressed the background (`Rectangle Fill`) of the button changes. So the user can see what buttons have been pressed and what not.

**Problem:**

I use a trigger and a `Togglebutton` to perform the `"IsChecked"` to change the  background.
But the background change may only happens 1 time.

*For example:*

Button Background = black --> `PRESS` --> Button Background = blue

But when i press the button again the Button BackGround changes back to black (since its a ToggleButton).

***How can i make sure the background only changes 1 time?***

**EDIT:** The button must remain enabled, because a user gives in a reason when they press the button. Meaning if they pick the wrong reason they are able to change it.

```
<Style x:Key="ButtonStyleReg" TargetType="{x:Type myClasses:RegButton}">
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
            <Grid x:Name="registrationButton">
                <Rectangle Name="rectangleBtn" Fill="#FF89959A" Height="Auto" RadiusY="15" RadiusX="15" Stroke="White" Width="Auto"/>

                <TextBlock x:Name="reason" TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                           Text="{Binding Reason, StringFormat=\{0\}}"
                           HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,7.5,0,0" Height="Auto" 
                           VerticalAlignment="Top" FontWeight="Bold" >
                </TextBlock>                                                                                   
            </Grid>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True"/>
                <!--<Trigger Property="IsDefaulted" Value="True"/>-->

                <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                    <Setter TargetName="rectangleBtn" Property="Fill" Value="blue" />
                </Trigger>                                                     
                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>

    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
<Setter Property="FontSize" Value="10.667"/>
```

Listbox that implements the style:

```
<ListBox x:Name="lbRegistration" ItemsSource="{Binding RegBtns, ElementName=Window}" Background="{x:Null}" 
            BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Grid.Column="1" 
            ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" Height="75">
            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>

            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <myClasses:RegistrationButton x:Name="RegistrationButton" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="71" Width="148" 
                                                  Margin="10,0,5,0" 
                                                  Style="{DynamicResource ButtonStyleRegistration}"
                                                  Click="RegistrationButton_Click"
                                                  Title="{Binding Title}"
                                                  Oorzaak="{Binding Oorzaak}"     

                                                  DuurStilstand="{Binding DuurStilstand, 
                                                        Converter={StaticResource  DateTimeConverter}}"

                                                  BeginStilstand="{Binding BeginStilstand}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

Best Regards, 
Pete

Comment: Disable the button after 1 click.

Comment: The button must remain enabled. Because when a user presses a button they can select a reason (which will be placed inside the button). If they choose the wrong one then they must be able to change it again! Regards Pete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simple would be if you can access the rectangle from code behind:

```
rectangleBtn.Fill = Brushes.Blue;
```

If you can't access it - make yourself two styles.
The one that is the original style, the other one is the Blue Style which shall be applied when the user clicks.

In the code behind, on event Click="RegistrationButton_Click"
Set the Style to the BlueStyle.

```
RegistrationButton.Style = this.FindResource("ButtonStyleRegistration") as Style;
```

Since you always want it blue, this code is enough as it is. It will always make it Blue for you.
The first time, and any other time.
That way you achieve your requirement and the style will change only once.
When the window is loaded, it will load into the original style (the first style).
So put in your XAML the style "Black" and in the code behind as shown above.

Then this must be removed:

```
<Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True"> 
    <Setter TargetName="rectangleBtn" Property="Fill" Value="blue" /> 
</Trigger>
```

Then this:

```
<myClasses:RegistrationButton x:Name="RegistrationButton" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="71" Width="148"  
Margin="10,0,5,0"  
Style="{DynamicResource ButtonStyleRegistration}" 
Click="RegistrationButton_Click"
```

Shall be:

```
<myClasses:RegistrationButton x:Name="RegistrationButton" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="71" Width="148"  
Margin="10,0,5,0"  
Style="{DynamicResource ButtonStyleRegBlack}" 
Click="RegistrationButton_Click"
```

That is all.

Comment: Do you want to keep your button enabled and press it as many times as you want or you want to be able to be pressed only once?

Comment: The button must remain press able. Users can give in a reason when they press the button. But if they have accidently choose the wrong reason they must be able to click it again! Best regards.

Comment: Do you change the background in code? Can you apply the check that I added above? Once the color is blue, then don't execute the code that changes it.

Comment: The background (which is actually the Fill of the Rectangle) changes with the "IsChecked" Trigger shown in my XAML. Not really sure how to access the Rectangle itself then...

Comment: Move your trigger to another event. Like Click event or whatever is available there.

Comment: It can be in the code behind if needed sure. Could you elaborate with a code example? When i did this in the "IsPressed" event the rectangle only changed background for 1 second while clicking it.

Comment: Ok, then register CLICK event. Inside it rectangleBtn.Fill = Brushes.Blue; or rectangleBtn.BackGround = Brushes.Blue;

Comment: Problem is i do not know how to access the rectangle from within the style. I used visualTreeHelper methods to access items from within a control but does not seem to work within a style.

Comment: I cannot just change my XAML? My button exists out of a rectangle and several textBlocks i cannot simply remove that? The rectangle is also acting as the "shape" of my button since is a custom styled button.

Comment: Okay many thanks Stefanov. It works perfectly although i hate pasting such long style twice in my code :D

Comment: Yes, that is the disadvantage :)

Comment: One last thing, if you decide to try it would be to keep the original way, but add another event (try tokeep the IsChecked and add the new one or only leave the new one) which is LostFocus. Then on this one also to set the Fill=Blue. Or on MouseUp event. I haven't tested it, but it might solve it for you. I don't know if GotFocus will "overwrite" the LostFocus event and you Fill will be lost?! Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using an MVVM approach I would recommend binding the background and the Click command to members in the ViewModel. The first time the button is clicked it sets a flag and changes the background color. The next time the button is clicked, if the flag is set, the command returns without changing the background.

XAML:

```
<ToggleButton Background="{Binding MyBackground}" Command="{Binding OnClickCmd}"/>
```

ViewModel

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
     public Brush MyBackground 
     { 
          get { return background_; } 
          set {
                background_ = value;
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArg("MyBackground");
          }
     }

     public ICommand OnClickCmd
     {
          get {
               return new DelegateCommand(()=>{ // DelegateCommand implements ICommand
                  if(!isBackgroundSet) {
                      background = Brushes.Red;
                      isBackgroundSet_ = true;    
                  }
               });
          }
     }

     private Brush background_;
     private bool isBackgroundSet_;
     private event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChagned;
 }
```

Comment: I am not using MVVM since i am new to WPF (but yeah i should have i know).